# how to bind multiple fields to same column in ListView/GridView?

Tags: wpf, gridview, listview, mvvm, binding

in a GridView column i need to display a string composed from a set of fields on my view model. how do i bind multiple fields to same column and how do i specify the format string to use for this column?

thanks for any help
konstantin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new property on your view model to bind to.  For example, lets say you have two properties, FirstName & LastName.  If you wanted to display the fullname in that column, you could create the new property to bind to, like this:

```
public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
```

Comment: this is a good idea, thanks. it has limitations though, such as it is more difficult to localize because it is in code, not in XAML.

Comment: Assuming that your localization binding is done using DynamicResources, you can still use those Resources in code-behind.

Comment: basically, the answer is that it is impossible, and i need to create a property that combines other properties.